# CAPTCHA stored in session?

Tags: php, forms, session, random

I made simple contact form and to prevent from spam I had to use captcha. 
Of course I thought using images or these weird almost not impossible to read letters is just annoying for user or me.

So what I did is just randomly created number and stored in session:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['var_answer']))
{
    $_SESSION['var_answer'] = rand (1, 100);
}
```

Then asked user to enter this number and when user submits the form, my code checks if random number created before and stored in session matches users entered number and sends the form away, then session is unset and we have another random number.

**Is it safe at all? Or this way is just useless protecting from spam?**

Comment: It is safe, but wouldn't a robot visiting your page create a session the same way a user would?

Comment: How would you create a session? By exiting browser everytime?

Comment: A session is created by PHP when your file containing `session_start` is served up, regardless to whether it is served to a browser or a bot.  It is the server execution that matters.

Comment: most CAPTCHAs are working with sessions and i consider them safe.
What i dont consider safe is to use plain numbers / text as captcha. These can be parsed kids playing in my opinion. I had the same problem of my-users-could-not-read-code and decided to use [this](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/) instead of captha,reCAPTCHA difficult reading codes. My point is, always choose images.

Answer (score 0):

i cant even say if its useless but what i do in my project is either use third party tools/software (theres so many of them) for captcha or generate it in a random text/number and make it into an image to prevent spam from bots i dont even intend storing them into a session.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is safe for general spamming robot that browse the web randomly. However if you are the target of a spammer that will code a bot specifically for your website, then, it can parge the number in your parse and put it in the requests.

You could build a simple image with the number, it could make it harder for the spammer.

Comment: Well I believe I could make this code a bit more difficult including character as well, not only the numbers.